# Is there a way to disable Game Center for an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

Say you have an app that had Game Center enabled at some point. Is there a way to tell Apple that that app doesn't use Game Center anymore so that it doesn't show up in the Game Center leaderboards, etc? The app is already not using the Game Center SDK so it doesn't share anything. There doesn't seem to be anything on iTunes connect or on the Provisioning Portal.

Comment: When I login to iTunesConnect, click on the app, and click on Manage Game Center, there is a big switch at the top to enable/disable game center. That doesn't do anything for you?

Comment: It doesn't let me tap on it. I guess you can only do it on an app that is in review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your app is approved, you have to click each version and in the version details, above the EULA and below the screenshots is a button to enable/disable Game Center for that version.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/15_GameCenter/GameCenter.html

Check out the bottom of this page:

> Distributing Game Center Apps
>
> You can enable a version of your app for Game Center at the time you
>   submit your app to the App Store. At this time you can select which
>   leaderboards and achievements you want to submit with that version of
>   your app. Also, you can select which apps and versions that you want
>   you app to be compatible with.
>
> If you use the multiplayer compatibility feature, you also need to
>   select the apps that are compatible with this version of your app on
>   the Version Details page.
>
> To enable a version of your app for Game Center Log in to iTunes
>   Connect using your Apple ID user name and password.
>
> Click Manage Your Applications.
>
> Click the app you want to manage.
>
> In the Versions section, click View Details next to the version you
>   want to edit.
>
> In the Game Center section, click Disabled.
>
> If you have leaderboards to submit with this version of your app,
>   click Edit in the Leaderboards section.
>
> Click Edit in the Leaderboards section.
>
> Select the leaderboards you want to submit.
>
> Click Save. If you have achievements to submit with this version of
>   your app, click Edit in the Achievements section.
>
> Click Edit in the Achievements section. Select the achievements you
>   want to submit. Click Save. If you have apps to add to the multiplayer
>   compatibility list or want to change the versions, click Edit in the
>   Multiplayer Compatibility section.
>
> Follow the same steps described in “To change set multiplayer
>   compatibility settings.”
>
> Click Ready to Upload Binary.
>
> If a version of your app was previously approved, you can no longer
>   disable Game Center for all versions of your app. Instead, you must
>   change Game Center properties for each version of your app separately.
>   If you disable a version of your app for Game Center, it may change
>   the multiplayer compatibility settings described in “Multiplayer
>   Compatibility Testing.”
>
> To disable a version of your app for Game Center Go to the details
>   page of the app version you want to edit.
>
> In the Game Center section, click Enabled.
>
> Occasionally, you may need to submit a version of your app without
>   groups and multiplayer compatibility enabled (perhaps you need to fix
>   a bug but are not ready to release the groups and multiplayer
>   compatibility version yet). To do this, you need to remove the app
>   from the group and deselect the versions of the app or any additional
>   apps you added from the multiplayer compatibility settings. Refer to
>   “Creating and Editing Groups” for how to remove an app from a group
>   and “Multiplayer Compatibility Testing” for how to change the
>   multiplayer compatibility settings.